# How to save and take global variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, global-variables

Please help me fix this code!:

first .m file:

```
NSInteger MYGlobalVariable = 0;
```

second .m file:

```
-(IBAction)globalvariable {
    if (NSInteger MYGlobalVariable = 0:
        [comp4nat setHidden = YES]);
}
```

Comment: A similar question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965347/objective-c-static-and-global-variable

Comment: wow, the syntax on that is awful, obviously not compiling, and I have no idea what you're trying to do with the code.  what is comp4nat? why are you using a colon?  so many other questions …  one suggestion: either expose the global variable as a class method, or make it an instance variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say exactly what you art trying to do here due to many syntax problems, but here's a guess:

```
- (IBAction)globalVariable {
    if (MYGlobalVariable == 0)
        [comp4nat setHidden:YES];
}
```

I have no idea if this is what you are trying to do, but at least it should compile. If this is not what you are trying to do then you should provide more information in your question.

Comment: Also note that this appears to be intended as an interface builder action method, but the signature doesn't comply so it won't work that way. If you want this to be invoked via an IB action, you should hang the first line to - (IBAction)globalVariable:(id)sender {

Comment: Tim that isn't necessary, IBActions can be either one argument (id)sender or zero arguments, either will work. Attaching sender is only normally needed if the method needs to incorporate logic dependant on the caller.